# Unable to install opencv's xfeatures2d module from the contrib repository

Tags: python, opencv, sift

I'm running **opencv-2.4.10** and need to get the **xfeatures2d** module from the contrib repository.

I run the following command:

```
cmake -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local -D OPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH=path to contrib/modules -D BUILD_opencv_xfeatures2d=ON path to opencv source dir
```

And get the following message:

> Module opencv_xfeatures2d disabled because opencv_shape dependency can't be resolved!

I can't seem to find a fix for this.

I would appreciate it if anyone knows a fix for this, or a possible workaround. Thanks.

Comment: you need opencv3.0 to use anything from the opencv_contrib repo. it will not work wit 2.4.x

Comment: So I fired up opencv 3.0 and the build went through with no errors, but when I include the flags to install the xfeatures2d module, I get the following error message:

make[2]: *** [modules/face/CMakeFiles/opencv_face.dir/src/eigen_faces.cpp.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [modules/face/CMakeFiles/opencv_face.dir/all] Error 2

Comment: ^^ this is not the actual error, please look a few lines up

Comment: There are multiple lines like this:

opencv_contrib-master/modules/face/include/opencv2/face/facerec.hpp:23:27: error: ‘NumComponents’ has not been declared
     CV_PURE_PROPERTY(int, NumComponents)

Comment: hmm, mshabunin has been refactoring all of this in the last days, so chances are, that you downloaded some intermediary broken contrib repo. but i was successful with today's copy, so - try to pull again ?

Comment: pull the main opencv repo, too ! better do a complete reload / rebuild. if hte error persists, disable the face module like: `cmake -D BUILD_opencv_face=OFF` and complain on the issues page

Comment: Okay so we scoured the issues page and found the same issue we had ( thank you so much for pointing us to that). Apparently opencv 3.0 + the current opencv_contrib is a no-go. We pulled the opencv-master repo and built it with the opencv-contrib and it worked! Thank you so much for your help!